# The value of the local variable '***' isn't used. Dart SWITCH statement

Tags: flutter, dart, switch-statement, local-variables, analyzer

I'm new to Dart and I'm hoping someone can explain this variable scoping warning.

When I use the following:

```
enum fruits {tomatoes, apples, oranges}

void main() {
  
  for (var item in fruits.values) {
    
    var color = 'red';          // Local variable 'color' declared
   
    switch (item){     
      case fruits.apples: 
       break; 
      case fruits.tomatoes:
       break;
      default:
       color = 'orange';        // Local variable 'color' used, analyzer doesn't see
       break;}  
    
    print (color);              // Local variable 'color' used, analyzer sees
    }
}
```

The code analyzer has no problem with the above. But if I comment out the print statement `// print (color);`, I get the warning `The value of the local variable 'color' isn't used.` from the analyzer even though `color` is used in the default case of the `switch` statement.

Why doesn't the analyzer "see" the local variable in the `default` case?

Comment: Assigning value to a variable does not mean using it. It does not contribute to any further computations so it's useless, therefore analyzer is telling you that.

Answer (score 2):

because assigning the variable colors is not consider using the variable.... for example printing the color consider using the variable.
When you use the color for a widget or any thing else then the lint will gone.